# How to deal with large json files (flattening it to tsv)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a large JSON file specifically the persona dataset ([download here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/datasets.huggingface.co/personachat/personachat_self_original.json))

> Each entry in Persona-Chat is a dict with two keys personality and
> utterances, and the dataset is a list of entries.
>
> ```
> personality: list of strings containing the personality of the agent
> utterances: list of dictionaries, each of which has two keys which are lists of strings.
> candidates: [next_utterance_candidate_1, ..., next_utterance_candidate_19]
> The last candidate is the ground truth response observed in the conversational data
> history: [dialog_turn_0, ... dialog_turn N], where N is an odd number since the other user starts every conversation.
> ```
>
> https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-chatbot-with-simple-transformers-da25160859f4

What I am trying to achieve is to flatten it and convert it to tsv in the following format:

```
 col_index, string (where  string is the personality, candidates and history
```

But
Whenever I try to load it and convert it to dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(r'path')
display(df)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Any help is appreciated whether articles or other libs/frameworks and approaches, even breadcrumbs!

Edit:
I am feeding it to another api which require tsv, I am thinking of a way to concatenate and preserve the structure to re-structure it again.

Comment: Don't use `pd.read_json()` to try to read non-tabular data. Just use `json.load()`.

Comment: Also, considering there's a variable number of entries in `personality` / `candidates` / `history`, your CSV file would be rather strange.

Comment: I am feeding it to another api which require tsv, I am thinking of a way to concatenate and preserve the structure to re-structure it again.


Thanks for the json.load() comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully flatten that file, you'd need something like

```
import json


def read_personachat_file(name="personachat_self_original.json"):
    with open(name, "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for entry_type, chats in data.items():
        for chat_id, chat in enumerate(chats):
            personality = "|".join(chat["personality"])
            for utt_id, utt in enumerate(chat["utterances"]):
                for key in ("candidates", "history"):
                    for phrase_id, phrase in enumerate(utt[key]):
                        yield (entry_type, chat_id, personality, utt_id, key, phrase_id, phrase)


for entry in read_personachat_file():
    print(entry)
```

The output will be something like

```
('train', 313, 'i like to wear red .|i wear a red purse .|i like to wear red shoes also .|i use red lipstick .|i drive a red car .', 5, 'candidates', 7, 'my sister will be my mom , she wants me to get married')
('train', 313, 'i like to wear red .|i wear a red purse .|i like to wear red shoes also .|i use red lipstick .|i drive a red car .', 5, 'candidates', 8, 'hi , how are ya ?')
('train', 313, 'i like to wear red .|i wear a red purse .|i like to wear red shoes also .|i use red lipstick .|i drive a red car .', 5, 'candidates', 9, 'sounds good . i am just sitting here with my dog . i love animals .')
('train', 313, 'i like to wear red .|i wear a red purse .|i like to wear red shoes also .|i use red lipstick .|i drive a red car .', 5, 'candidates', 10, "sure i'll go with you but i am baking a pizza right now , my favorite . come eat .")
('train', 313, 'i like to wear red .|i wear a red purse .|i like to wear red shoes also .|i use red lipstick .|i drive a red car .', 5, 'candidates', 11, 'where do you work then soccer person ?')
('train', 313, 'i like to wear red .|i wear a red purse .|i like to wear red shoes also .|i use red lipstick .|i drive a red car .', 5, 'candidates', 12, 'it is so pretty in the fall and winter , my favorite time to go')
('train', 313, 'i like to wear red .|i wear a red purse .|i like to wear red shoes also .|i use red lipstick .|i drive a red car .', 5, 'candidates', 13, 'i to travel and meet new people')
```

(whether or not that's useful for you).

Comment: Thanks, this a great start, enjoy some coffee on me.