# How to read CoQA dataset as pandas dataframe using read_json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I want to read the CoQA dataset(which is in JSON format)into a pandas' dataframe.

The link to the dataset: http://downloads.cs.stanford.edu/nlp/data/coqa/coqa-train-v1.0.json , I just downloaded it and want to use it locally.

My code is:

```py
#pandas dataset
import pandas as pd 

coqa = pd.read_json("./coqa-train-v1.0.json")
coqa.head()
```

However, I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-d5aafc2aac31> in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 
----> 4 coqa = pd.read_json("./coqa-train-v1.0.json")
      5 coqa.head()

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    294                 )
    295                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 296             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    297 
    298         return wrapper

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression, nrows)
    616         return json_reader
    617 
--> 618     result = json_reader.read()
    619     if should_close:
    620         filepath_or_buffer.close()

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in read(self)
    753                 obj = self._get_object_parser(self._combine_lines(data))
    754         else:
--> 755             obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
    756         self.close()
    757         return obj

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _get_object_parser(self, json)
    775         obj = None
    776         if typ == "frame":
--> 777             obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
    778 
    779         if typ == "series" or obj is None:

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in parse(self)
    884 
    885         else:
--> 886             self._parse_no_numpy()
    887 
    888         if self.obj is None:

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1117         if orient == "columns":
   1118             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1119                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1120             )
   1121         elif orient == "split":

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

But when I try it using URL, there's nothing wrong:

```py
import pandas as pd
coqa = pd.read_json('http://downloads.cs.stanford.edu/nlp/data/coqa/coqa-train-v1.0.json')
coqa.head()
```

Comment: You can't read a nested/structured JSON file directly using `pd.read_json()`. What would you imagine the column structure for that dataset to look like? If you just want to read it as a dict, use `json.load()`.

Comment: As an aside, here's a related answer of mine for another similar dataset: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67626779/51685

Comment: @AKX But why there's nothing wrong when I using `pd.read_json()` and read directly from URL?